# float decimal en android

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Tengo una apk para cargar pagos, donde se adjuntan detalles de transferencias. Entre varias opciones existe un campo donde se introduce un monto con decimales. Al momento de intentar editar el monto, muestra este error y me regresa a la pantalla anterior.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo

```
 }
            iv6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            etvalor.setText(min);

            s = Float.parseFloat(min);
            Float Bsf = Float.parseFloat(tasa)*s;
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tasa.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Locale currentLocale = Locale.GERMAN;
            otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(currentLocale);
            otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
            otherSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');

            df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00", otherSymbols);
            String numberAsString = df.format(Bsf);
            etBsf.setText(numberAsString);
            etBsfpromo.setText(numberAsString);
            String tasaAsString = df.format(Float.parseFloat(tasa));
            tvTasa.setText(tasaAsString);
            final String finalTasa = tasa;
            etvalor.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                          int count) {
                    if(!s.equals("") ) {
                        //do your work here
                    }
                }
```

Añadiré mas texto que podría ser de interés.

```
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                              int after) {

                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    Float w = null;
                    if(checkboxpromo.isChecked()){
                        w = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(etvalor))*(1+(Float.parseFloat(valorp.get(spinnerpromo.getSelectedItemPosition()))/100));
                        valorpromo = valorp.get(spinnerpromo.getSelectedItemPosition());

                    }else {
                        w = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(etvalor));
                        valorpromo="0";
                    }
                    Float w1 = Float.parseFloat(finalTasa)*w;
                    String numberAsString3 = df.format(w1);
                    etBsf.setText(numberAsString3);
                    etBsfpromo.setText(numberAsString3);
                }
                
            });
```

agradezco cualquier aporte!

Answer (score 2):

El error `NumberFormatException` se produce cuando tratas de convertir a Float un valor que no es numérico en estos puntos:

```
 s = Float.parseFloat(min);
 ...
 ...
 String tasaAsString = df.format(Float.parseFloat(tasa));
```

En este caso te sugiero usar un método para validar usando el siguiente método:

```
   public static boolean isFloat(String number){
        try {
            return !new Float(number).isNaN();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

y validarías de esta forma, en caso de no ser numerico el valor predeterminado sería 0:

```
  s = Float.parseFloat(isFloat(min)?min:"0");
 ...
 ...
  String tasaAsString = df.format(Float.parseFloat(isFloat(tasa)?tasa:"0"));
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu aporte, he añadido mas informacion sobre el codigo. Intenté realizar esa modificacion pero no me funciono, existe un error en "isFloat" . Muchas gracias